# How to extract first name in list

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Hi so I'm printing out a list of usernames using the code below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Username':commentor_list})
df1.assign(Username=df1.Username.str.split(",")).explode('Username')
```

However, some usernames output with extra info like the following:

```
Alice (10 videos / 58 subscribers)
Bob
Charles (20 videos / 28 subscribers)
Diana
```

I want to extract the first names to get

```
Alice 
Bob
Charles 
Diana
```

I've tried using the code below, as well as '[\S]' and '[\w] ' but nothing works. I get the error 'pattern contains no capture groups'

```
df1['Username'] = df1['Username'].str.extract('[?:\S]')
print(df1)
```

Can someone please help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of `explode`, I will use `expand=True` with `.str.split`:

```
df1['Username'] = df1['Username'].str.split(" ",expand=True)[0]
```

Comment: actually I have one more question- if someone's name is Alison Lisa James, how can I print all of that as well?

Comment: If that's the case then split on the parentheses: `df1['Username'] = df1['Username'].str.split("(",expand=True)[0]`

Comment: thank you for getting back to me so quickly! I really appreciate your help. That works!